# Insufficient privileges to complete the operation when adding a member to a Microsoft 365 group

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

While adding a member to a Microsoft 365 Group with permission type: Delegated - I am using the following error:

```
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

As per Microsoft's documentation - all the required permissions are added in the AD App: `GroupMember.ReadWrite.All, Group.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All, Directory.AccessAsUser.All`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

I am using the same code request provided by Microsoft:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var directoryObject = new DirectoryObject
{
    Id = "{id}"
};

await graphClient.Groups["{group-id}"].Members.References
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(directoryObject);
```

[image]

**What permissions are still missing ?**

Comment: @Tarkan Sevilmis: if you can help here as well.

Answer (score 1):

The missing role was User Administrator Role - once my "user" account got added I was able to add/remove the users.

[image]